# Conditionally show specific blocks in mail templates based on store config for a store view

Tags: email-templates, magento2.3.1

Is it possible to show / hide different blocks in mail templates, based on store configuration entries?

We know about `{{if ... }}` and `{{config path="config/path"}}` but how can this be combined?

Comment: You could extend `Magento\Framework\Filter\Template` to process more in `if` statement conditions. Something like this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257847/magento-2-add-customer-group-as-email-template-variable/258716#258716  And add regular expressions/code to process `{{config path` directive.